# What are my alternatives to modal or modeless dialogs to display information and contact forms?

Tags: html, css

I have a couple of links on an in-progress website that will display what I am calling 'one-shot' information - stuff like a bit about the project and contact forms etc that I really don't want to have to make the user reload a page for.

Originally I thought that I would like to display these as modal (or mode-less) windows, thereby stopping extra page loads and keeping with my remit of trying to deliver as much as possible within one load of the page.

However, I have zero JS knowledge so I have failed miserably at trying to implement a modal window system.  Question 1 - ***is there any alternatives to modal dialogs that would be better suited that I haven't thought about?***  I'm thinking the only other option is a CSS popup which would do the same without the JS.

I think I may have to resign myself to separate page loads, so the other situation is that I have a side bar with a music player and other data.  I would ideally like to not have a user click a link and it reload the music player (ie it keeps playing as the user navigates to this one-shot information), 1) due to the user experience of stopping and starting music, and 2) so multiple re-starts doesn't affect the play count.  That in mind...

Question 2 - ***is there anything I can use in the same way as a HTML frames setup used to that is non-dodgy, or would I have to just accept reloads of the player?***

Comment: @Dibya I haven't yet tried anything other than a failed attempt to produce a modal dialog.  I have tried jQuery UI Dialog, FancyBox, and a tutorial from raventools that I got working, but because it didn't look like other examples it confused me.

Comment: You can do fancy contact pages by using JS refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662891/validating-form-using-javascript and you may also see cutmblog.hostzi.com. It is a poorly organized page but helpful for beginners. You can make it well structured

Comment: Haven't u got a correct answer yet?

Comment: lol I thought I had accepted your answer earlier.  I've done my duty thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modal pops are the best practice. I won't advice to go for any other technique for contact forms. There is a straight forward technique `HTML <form>` use it if you don't like complexity.
Sample code for a simple `HTML form`

```
<div id == "errorresponse"></div>
<form name = "myform" action = "action.php" method = "post" onSubmit = "validate()">
<input type = "text" name = "firstname"/>
<input type = "text" name = "email"/>
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Click Here to Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Dibya.  I will look into this, but I'm disappointed that modals are the best practice as I am struggling to understand how to code it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Expand and Collapse method to display your different link information.
That would be easier and won't require page reloads.

Also Modal popup is an good option but number of clicks increases in it.

Both type of demo you can find in below link.

websemantics.co.uk/resources/accessible_css3_modal_pop-ups/