# How to build a window like control on HTML5 webpage?

Tags: html, window, controls

I am making the control shown in the image. It has a title bar and a set of controls inside it. What would be the best way to build it? It is part of a HTML5 webpage.

http://tinypic.com/r/25rpk4o/6

One way is to draw the title bar with canvas rect and then place all the controls under it. The collapsing can be done with javascript. But there must be a better way.

Another way I thought of was to make a table and have the first row as the title bar and add the sub-controls in the 2nd row. It seems to work fine but VS2012 keeps telling me that I can't nest button inside a tr.

Answer (score 0):

This question or similar was asked on stackoverflow here...

[What are my alternatives to modal or modeless dialogs to display information and contact forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367389/what-are-my-alternatives-to-modal-or-modeless-dialogs-to-display-information-and)

Maybe the last thread on that post can give you some examples??

The direct link to the external examples is

http://websemantics.co.uk/resources/accessible_css3_modal_pop-ups/

Comment: Hi Zaf, I don't really want a pop-up. I want it to be a part of my parent page itself.

Answer (score 0):

Okay Sorry I misunderstood your initial meaning.

Well you can have a look at the below two files, one is a web page and the other is user control, the user control Copy and paste the code into two new files and see what you think?

I tried to recreate the control from your original pic that you uploaded and have used a TABLE tag, although you can probably cut down the html code by using DIVS instead.

## File 1

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<%@ Register src="MyInlineWindow.ascx" tagname="MyInlineWindow" tagprefix="uc1" %>
<!-- HTML5 -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/vbscript">
    Sub ShowInlineWindow()
    dim el
      set el = window.document.getElementById("MyInlineWindowCtrl")
      window.document.getElementById("Result").innerhtml = "Nothing"
      el.style.display = "block"
    End Sub

    Sub HideInlineWindow(YesNo)
    dim el
      set el = window.document.getElementById("MyInlineWindowCtrl")
      window.document.getElementById("Result").innerhtml = YesNo
      el.style.display = "none"
    End Sub
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Interact" onclick="ShowInlineWindow()" /><br />[<label id="Result">Nothing</label>]
    <br /><br /><br /><br />
    <uc1:MyInlineWindow ID="MyInlineWindow1" runat="server" />
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

## File 2

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" ClassName="MyInlineWindow" %>
<table id="MyInlineWindowCtrl" style="display: none; border: 1px solid #333333; width: 640px;">
<tr>
    <td colspan="4" style="border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px; background-color: #808080; color: #FFFFFF;">Window Title</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td style="width: 25%;">
        <table style="margin 8px: width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td>Label</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>
                    <select id="Select1" name="D1">
                        <option>Some drop down</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>Label</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>
                    <select id="Select2" name="D2">
                        <option>Some drop down</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 25%;">
        <table style="margin 8px: width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td>Label</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td><input id="Radio1" checked="true" name="R1" type="radio" value="V1" /> Label</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td><input id="Radio2" checked="true" name="R2" type="radio" value="V1" /> Label</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td><input id="Radio3" checked="true" name="R3" type="radio" value="V1" /> Label</td>
            </tr><tr>
            <td><input id="Radio4" checked="true" name="R4" type="radio" value="V1" /> Label</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 25%;">
        <table style="margin 8px: width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">Label</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>From</td>
                <td>To</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>
                    <select id="Select3" name="D3">
                        <option>Date Picker</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="Select4" name="D4">
                        <option>Date Picker</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td><input id="Radio5" checked="true" name="R5" type="radio" value="V1" /> Label</td>
                <td><input id="Radio6" checked="true" name="R6" type="radio" value="V1" /> Label</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 25%;">
        <table style="margin 8px: width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td style="text-align: center">
                    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="HideInlineWindow('Cancel')" />
                    <input id="Button2" type="button" value="Okay" onclick="HideInlineWindow('Okay')" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Maybe it is closer to what you want.
Also I have used VB script as thats what i know best, but it should not be too difficult to port/transpose it into Javascript.